# Code First and Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I have the following question.

I try to execute stored procedure which returns a table with Entity Framework 5 in MVC 4 application using Code First model.

First, I have an `Entity` called `Genres`:

```
public class Genres
{
    [Key]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int Artists { get; set; }
    public int Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a `DbContext`:

```
public class DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Genres> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

And then, I execute my stored procedure with `SqlQuery`:

```
        var DbContext = new DbContext();

        ViewBag.Genres = DbContext.Genres.SqlQuery("psy_trance_fm_select_genres");
```

Everything works well, but I have a question.

When I execute my stored procedure Entity Framework 5 creates two tables in my database. First one is `__MigrationHistory`, second one is `Genres`.

I don't need `Genres` table to be created because I don't use it at all.

Please help me with it. Thanks.

PS - I wrote my code with the help of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Stored Procedure then you should not be using Code-First strategy.

You should be using Database-First strategy because having a Stored Procedure implies the existance of a database.

And your `Genre` table gets created because that is what Code-First does - it created tables in the database from entities created in code.

Database-First strategy, on the other hand, would import your existing database schema and create entities from that. Including strongly-typed Stored Procedures.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) is a video + tutorial on MSDN explainin the concepts of Database-First strategy with Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, juhan_h. Can you tell me, there can I read more about different models and, especially, Database-First model. Thanks!

Comment: I added link to my answer that points you to a tutorial on MSDN. Hope it helps.

Comment: And one more question. Would it be good idea to rewrite all of my SPs with EF Code-First model and LINQ? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your SP-s if they are complicated (using temp tables/cursors etc) they should remain. But if you are doing Inserts/Selects with SP-s then I would recommend using LINQ queries because they are testable and easily maintainable then SP-s.

Comment: Time to move to LINQ :). Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading, especially in the use of Code-First strategy. I know it can be a bit misleading, but the Code-First _pattern_ can be used with an existing database. Personally, I prefer to use Code-First on an existing database because it allows for cleaner code than the database-first pattern (which results in auto-generated files like edmx, ick).